# vue-router does not stay on same page after a page refresh

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have two routes on vue-router, /user/:uid and /itinerary/:id. The first route is shown after the user logs in and from there they select the itinerary they want to view which would bring them to the next route.

While on /itinerary/:id, if I do a page refresh/reload/f5 I see the browser address bar back on /user/:uid. In the vue-devtools, it just resets to showing /user/:uid (not a case of some router.push() or whatever). Why is this happening and how can I keep the user on /itinerary/:id even if they refresh the page?

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: LoginPanel },
  {
    path: '/user/:uid',
    component: ItineraryList,
    beforeEnter: authGuard,
  },
  {
    path: '/itinerary/:itinerary_id',
    name: 'itineraryView',
    component: ItineraryBuilder,
    beforeEnter: authGuard,
  },
];

function authGuard(to, from, next) {
  // retrieved from localStorage
  if (idToken && userEmail) {
    next();
  } else {
    next('/');
    window.alert('Please login first');
  }
}
```

Edit: Added relevant code from ItineraryBuilder

```
beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
    if (this.confirmed) { // set on data() property
        next();
    } else {
        this.$modal.show('dialog', {
            title: 'Confirm save new changes?',
            text: '',
            buttons: [{
                title: 'Yes',
                handler: () => { 
                    let itinerary_id = this.$route.params.itinerary_id
                    let queries = [];
                    this.itinerary.forEach(item => {
                        console.log(item);
                        let board_id = item.doc_id;
                        queries.push(db.collection('itineraries').doc(board_id).set(item, { merge: true }));
                    });

                    Promise.all(queries).then(() => {
                        // this.$store.commit('UPDATE_ITINERARY', this.itinerary);
                        this.$modal.hide('dialog');
                        this.confirmed = true
                        eventBus.$emit('itinerary_saved', true);
                        next();
                    })
                }
            },
            {
                title: 'No',
                handler: () => {
                    this.$modal.hide('dialog');
                    next(false);
                }
            }]
        });
    }
}
```

I didn't notice it at first, but could it be related? I'm using `this.confirm` as a flag to handle if there are any changes made by the user, I'll emit a change event and set the flag to false - meaning there are unsaved changes so the current state is unconfirmed.

Comment: Please share the code for `ItineraryBuilder` component. The routing code seems to be ok.

Comment: Do you have history mode enabled in vue-router? https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html

Comment: @Dylan Thanks for the response. No, I do not have history mode enabled.

Comment: @HarshalPatil Thanks for the response. I've added the part where I'm doing anything with routing.. I hope it helps.

Comment: Any ideas folks? :/ Do you need me to post more code?

Comment: I have the same issue but only if I use "mode: 'history'" in Vue.Router(). Any ideas?